# Xamarin ImageButton goes invisible after clicked

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, imagebutton

I have an image button which when I click I want to change its Source (an empty star to a filled one) for the ratings.

My XAML:

```xml
<StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0">
    <ImageButton Source="star_empty.png"
                 HeightRequest="40"
                 WidthRequest="40"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 x:Name="star1"
                 BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                 Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked" />

    <ImageButton Source="star_empty.png"
                 HeightRequest="40"
                 WidthRequest="40"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 x:Name="star2"
                 BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                 Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked2" />

    <ImageButton Source="star_empty.png"
                 HeightRequest="40"
                 WidthRequest="40"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 x:Name="star3"
                 BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                 Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked3" />

    <ImageButton Source="star_empty.png"
                 HeightRequest="40"
                 WidthRequest="40"
                 x:Name="star4"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                 Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked4" />

    <ImageButton Source="star_empty.png"
                 HeightRequest="40"
                 WidthRequest="40"
                 x:Name="star5"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                 Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked5" />
</StackLayout>
```

The View class:

```cs
private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    star1.Source = "star_full.png";
    int rating = 1;
}
```

What could be the issue? The Source does change, it just blinks then goes invisible. I set the isVisible property to true, that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the type of ImageSource you are using; file, resource, uri, stream:

#### Example:

```cs
star1.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("star_full.png");
```

#### Update:

```xml
<StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0">
        <ImageButton x:Name="star1" Source="star_off.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"/>
        <ImageButton x:Name="star2" Source="star_off.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"/>
        <ImageButton x:Name="star3" Source="star_off.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"/>
        <ImageButton x:Name="star4" Source="star_off.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"/>
        <ImageButton x:Name="star5" Source="star_off.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```cs
void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as ImageButton).Source = ImageSource.FromFile("star_on.png");
}
```

[image]

Comment: When I did my code for the 5th star, the 5th (clicked) went invisible, but the first 4 were good, when defining `FromResource` all of them went invisible, `FromFile` does the same as my code.

Comment: @ChrisFodor What type of images are you using? (Embedded Resources? Android Resource-based Drawables, etc...?)

Comment: Android resources in the Drawables folder

Comment: Are you sure that the image button content's are visible after the image switch, try adding `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"` to your ImageButton XAML as a test (and in your case `FromFile` is correct)

Comment: I´ve added it, but its still doing it, I´have provided the full XAML code in my OP now for better understanding.

Comment: Thanx, turns out the WidthRequest and HeightRequest were the issue.